# Why are apache&nginx &tomcat access_log the same format？

Tags: apache, tomcat, logging, nginx, file-format

It looks like this:

> `120.3.14.4 - - [02/Jul/2014:12:27:53 +0800] "GET /wwe/index.php?config=localhost HTTP/1.1" 404 952 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0)"`

Answer (score 0):

Because they all use the NCSA [Combined Log Format](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/ITWSA/ITWSA_info45/en_US/HTML/guide/c-logs.html#combined), which is designed so web analysis tools and so forth can parse the same format easily.